# How can I purge my Haskell installation from my Windows XP machine?

Tags: haskell

I tried uninstalling the Haskell Platform, but the package database remains intact. How can I completely purge Haskell from my system?

Comment: You should probably learn to use Cabal sandboxes to avoid these kinds of version conflicts in the future. Another system some people swear by is Stackage, which seems to be a sort of "everything works with everything else" extension of the Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 9):

Both cabal and ghc maintain some extra data that isn't currently uninstalled by the platform installer, thankfully however they're well behaved and store their data in appropriate application data folders.

Assuming you've only installed user level packages, the easiest way to delete them on the windows platform is to type `%APPDATA%` in the windows run dialog or windows explorer bar, this should open the root of the application data folder, then delete the `ghc` and `cabal` folders.

As an aside, before uninstalling the platform you can use use the command `ghc-pkg list --user` to see what user level packages are installed, the top of the list will include the path where ghc stores local user files. Obviously leaving out the `--user` flag will provide system wide information.

If you weren't aware of the `ghc-pkg` program take a look at `ghc-pkg --help` as you can often resolve package issues using it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

On my system (Windows XP), Cabal stores files in the following places:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\cabal
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\lib
```

The first location is for "local" package installations, the second for "global" package installations. On Windows, Cabal usually defaults to local, but you can ask it to do global instead.

You can just *delete* the folder under `Documents and Settings`. The HP uninstaller should have removed everything under `Program Files`, but perhaps it doesn't work if you've done some global installs. (?)

That's my best guess, anyway. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the contents of the package directory. I'm uncertain of where it is (something equivelant to $HOME/.cabal on Windows) but, you can find it from GHCI:

```
:m System.Directory
getAppUserDataDirectory "cabal"
```

Edit: I think this would be `$HOME/Application Data/cabal` if you have a newer version of Windows.

Comment: I uninstalled the Haskell Platform deleted the package directory but when I reinstalled the Haskell Platform and tried reinstalling a package, cabal said the package was already installed!

Answer (score 0):

Cabal is also placed here:
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin`